# How to stop the output of snmpwalk command after few seconds automatically

Tags: unix

I have to write a script to automate snmpwalk command. The input is a text file which contains community string and its respective IP address. If for a IP address i have to stop the output of snmpwalk command after few seconds , then how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the timeout command is what you are looking for.

```
timeout 1s sleep 10
```

... returns after 1 second.

```
timeout 3s snmpwalk -v2c -c public myhost.mydomain
```

... runs a snmpwalk and returns after max. 3 seconds.

If the timeout command is not available on your system, see below a more general solution using perl.

```
perl -e 'alarm shift @ARGV; exec @ARGV' 3 snmpwalk -v2c -c public myhost.mydomain
```

... runs a snmpwalk and returns after max. 3 seconds.

The command "shift @ARGV" takes the first element out of the argument array (e.g.: alarm 3). The second command "exec @ARGV", executes the rest of the argument array (e.g.: exec 'snmpwalk -v2c -c public myhost.mydomain').

So the oneliner above expands to the following perl script:

```
alarm 3;
exec 'snmpwalk -v2c -c public myhost.mydomain';
```

Comment: I am using bash shell in red hat environment. Its coming no command found, if i am using timeout. should i use differently

Comment: I am sorry to ask this silly doubt, but i don't know anything about perl. But can i use perl keyword in unix

Comment: One more help , can you tell me a little bit logic behind this perl command

Comment: Use the command "yum provides /usr/bin/timeout", to check if it is available in your software repository

Comment: I've edited the post according your question.

Comment: Oh...i got the logic now!! Thanks a lot for your help :)

Comment: would you mind to accept the answer, if it's working now?

Comment: Yes , it's perfectly working. Thanks once again.

Comment: @taruni: The idea of stackoverflow is, that you use the accept button, if you are fine with an answer.

Comment: Uhmm..sorry , but where is the accept button. I am not able to locate it.

Comment: there should be a tick under the up/down vote. maybe it is disabled because the question is "on hold"

Comment: Yeah, i am not able to see the tick.

Comment: I got it , it was below zero